# Executing python with input argumant in Virtual environment

Tags: linux, python-3.x, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook

I have a running Python virtual environment and a python code, `code.py`, and a text file as input parameters , `input.txt`. I'm using `Jupyter`. The python code and the text file are located in different directories. In the terminal When I try this after activating virtual environment:

```
code.py input.txt
```

At the end it wants to plot something but can't. Any idea how it is possible to run that in `Jupyter`?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @TheoB, unfortunately , currently I do not have access to the code

Comment: you need to post the error and the code here in order to get help. Which OS do you use?

Comment: @TheoB code is in a remote linux, my local OS is Windows using PUTTY. The error is:  `no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

Comment: Has -X solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to login with the -X flag to set the $DISPLAY-var

```
ssh -X "your_login"
```

Comment: My problem is not how to read input file. When I call the code.py, I get ` no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable` error

Comment: are you running this through `ssh`?

Comment: Yes, I am running that through SSh

Comment: do you start it with -X -flag?

Comment: No I do not execute that with -X flag

Comment: try to login with -X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146943/discussion-between-theob-and-super-hornet).